# why ConditionalType resolves to different type than expected?

Tags: typescript, generics

I wonder why TypeScript resolves conditional type to `never` if I add a constraint that should guaranty desire type.

#### Example

Let's say we have written such code

```js
type PrimitiveDataType = string | number | bigint | boolean | symbol | undefined | null;

type ConditionalType<T> = T extends PrimitiveDataType
  ? (v: T) => void
  : never;

abstract class AbstractClass<T> {
  abstract value: T;
  protected conditionalFunctions: Map<ConditionalType<T>, number | undefined> = new Map();
}

class SomeClass<T extends PrimitiveDataType> extends AbstractClass<T> {
  value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    super();
    this.value = value;
  }

  someMethod() {
    for (const someFn of this.conditionalFunctions.keys()) {
      someFn(this.value);
    }
  }
}
```

> ***[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)***

In the above code I have created a `PrimitiveDataType` which is a union of all primitive data types in JavaScript.

Then I have created a `ConditionalType<T>` that will resolve to some callback only if `T` is one of `PrimitiveDataType`.

Then I have created an abstract generic class that have a field which type(`ConditionalType<T>`) depends on generic value of this class.

In the end, I have crated a `SomeClass` that extends `AbstractClass<T>` and add constraints that generic parameter `T` have to extend `PrimitiveDataType` and I get this error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'PrimitiveDataType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.   
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

#### Conclusion

I thought if in `SomeClass` `T` have a constraint that it have to be one on `PrimitiveDataType` then TypeScript will resolve `conditionalFunctions` field to be a type of `Map<(v: T) => void, number | undefined>`. To my surprise TypeScript resolves this type to `Map<(v: never) => void, number | undefined>` what is not clear for me and I do not know where is a mistake in the way how do I think about this?

Can you explain to me why this work like that, or maybe it is bug in TypeScript compiler?

##### Observations

If I leave only one, type in `PrimitiveDataType` then everything works okay but for more than one I am getting an error

#### Edit 1

If my conditional type has more than two possible return types, then distributive `[T]` doesn't work and gives such error:

```
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
```

> Looks like now TS resolves this type to type mapped for Array. I totally don't understand it now

**Example**

```js
type PrimitiveDataType = string | number | bigint | boolean | symbol | undefined | null;

type ConditionalType<T> = [T] extends [PrimitiveDataType]
  ? (v: T) => void
  : T extends Array<unknown>
  ? (v: T, t: number) => void
  : never;

abstract class AbstractClass<T> {
  abstract value: T;
  protected conditionalFunctions: Map<ConditionalType<T>, number | undefined> = new Map();
}

class SomeClass<T extends PrimitiveDataType> extends AbstractClass<T> {
  value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    super();
    this.value = value;
  }

  someMethod() {
    for (const someFn of this.conditionalFunctions.keys()) {
      someFn(this.value);
    }
  }
}
```

> ***[TS Playground - EDIT 1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbhAIgQ2DgFXGgF4oBnYRAOwHMoAfKagVyQCMI5Gp2FaE1YD3YB7UQBsIOaj3IgOkni2oATCADNBEVT1YSJAbgBQx0JCgBhUWtQIbOCUUgAeAgD4oZANoEAulAQAB7AEGrkUN7wyHaYuPjOEH7GUFAA-FAAFOgAXFAEAJRenuiiCKopUHkEgSFhqhEAgnBwOCAuKgDW1KIA7tTulRnZ1QA0UMB5rBxcRSQlZRWpUxCYcCbGOOyUrQDGwrsSOORN21Q4+5ZHJ26eAN6VWzsXwuiOLBDVJqlgcKKh+x0UF2NlUdgcEgAYip9vZqOQ8gBZHBgFzWWxoCGJW7jaacbhMFTqLTUHSeMik3pQZFgTIFEwAX1Mh2OEQAyqIkBArqy3LVQuFYIgUGg4nhCMRPMEBQ0oI0zntgDybh4oA9Um8JB8vqZUiD4VQWPtRHBsu9PvkiurUhQWJBTfTKqlgAALBDkAB0mo+Xig3og3ygTMq5E5EEREFdolUdLVTqgGhNWX1lAoYchslEGgmbs9+rBmOojmh1FhNk9nQgIHIdKt8dSoa5GcyrvdXvNjptQcqTIZQA)***

In my opinion, this should work the same as in this example:

```js
type PrimitiveDataType = string | number | bigint | boolean | symbol | undefined | null;

type ConditionalType<T> = [T] extends [PrimitiveDataType]
  ? (v: T) => void
  : T extends Array<unknown>
  ? (v: T, t: number) => void
  : never;

const x: PrimitiveDataType = 12;
const y: ConditionalType<typeof x> = (param: number) => undefined;
```

> ***[TS Playground - variables example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbhAIgQ2DgFXGgF4oBnYRAOwHMoAfKagVyQCMI5Gp2FaE1YD3YB7UQBsIOaj3IgOkni2oATCADNBEVT1YSJAbgBQx0JCgBhUWtQIbOCUUgAeAgD4oZANoEAulAQAB7AEGrkUN7wyHaYuPjOEH7GUFAA-FAAFOgAXFAEAJRenuiiCKopUHkEgSFhqhEAgnBwOCAuKgDW1KIA7tTulRnZ1QA0UMB5rBxcRSQlZRWpUxCYcCbGAMY2lFBBedEoaHF4hMReUACMAEwm29S7IHnWtmgOTsQu5hCiGnueZEyYBwrSQc08KnUWmoOkMQA)***

There is no problem and `ConditionalType<typeof x>` is resolved to `(v: number) => void` so what I would expect.

Answer (score 2):

Your generic type `ConditionalType<T>` produces a [distributive type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) when given a union.

For example when given the union `string | number` it results in the following type

```
type Foo = ConditionalType<string | number>
// ((v: string) => void) | ((v: number) => void)
```

Wrap either side of the condition in square brackets to avoid this

```
type ConditionalType<T> = [T] extends [PrimitiveDataType]
  ? (v: T) => void
  : never;
```

The above now generates the following, non-distributive, type which should work for your abstract class

```
type Foo = ConditionalType<string | number>
// (v: string | number) => void
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbhAIgQ2DgFXGgF4oBnYRAOwHMoAfKagVyQCMI5Gp2FaE1YD3YB7UQBsIOaj3IgOkni2oATCADNBEVT1YSJAbgBQx0JCgBhUWtQIbOCUUgAeAgD4oZANoEAulAQAB7AEGrkUN7wyHaYuPjOEH7GUFAA-FAAFOgAXFAEAJRenuiiCKopUHnUEJhwJmbEUABi4l5WNqp2Dk7ELpQ09EysHFzuJgD0E6lQAHpppjjsAzgAxsKrEjjkEQCCy1RrwJZbO26eAN6VSyvrUOiOLBB5BCapYHCioes6UKud3WojmaKnW9mo5DyAFkcGAXNZbGgeolzgAaZhsTjcJgqdRaGqqTxkGoAdygMLAmQKJgAvqZNtsIgBlURICAnRluQIhMKqCLRFBoOJ4QjETzBULhKD7W7HU7kc5QK6pB4SJ4vBqpf4QqgsdaiODZR7PfJFZUzcgsSCG6mVVLAAAWCHIADpVU92u6IG8oHTKuRWRAoRBHaJVFSlXaoBoDVltZQKIHmrJRBooI7nS7tV0kUCJCDqGCbK6ANYQEDkKlmqOpANs5OZDOur22ma+yp0mlAA)

Comment: I haven't heard about distributive type. Good to learn sth new. Thx mate

Comment: this distributive types doesn't work if my conditional type can resolve to more than only to types. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work now? (check EDIT 1)

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite junior on typescript, I've been using it for more or less a year and a half, but I'll still try to help you and give you a possible explanation to the error you encountered (at least what I think is the explanation), and possible ways to fix it.

/* =============== EXPLANATION =============== */

One reason, and the one that makes the most sense to me here, could be that the type narrowing wasn't sufficient. Why?

In the code you provided you defined the type `ConditionalType<T>` to be a function that returns `void` when `T` is a `PrimitiveDataType` and `never` when `T` is not a `PrimitiveDataType`. This is logically correct, however the way you are using this function type could be not the best. This function type purpose is to `narrow the type` of `T` type and should be used as a `type guard`. When you declare the class `SomeClass` however the `T` type is extending the raw `PrimitiveDataType` and not the `narrowed` type, so in the `for` loop you are checking if a raw type `PrimitiveDataType` is a valid `key` of the `narrowed` type version (as you declared in the `AbstractClass`), but of course `never` does not exists on the `PrimitiveDataType`. That's why you should extend `T` in the class `SomeClass` declaration as shown in the second fix i provided you below. In that way `T` will also inlcude `never` by default. And so `value` type will be the `narrowed` version type aka `ConditionalType<PrimitiveDataType>` and not `PrimitiveDataType`.

I hope you understood my point (my english still not very good haha).

/* =============== FIXES =============== */

I'm gonna provide you two ways to fix this, with the second one being the most type-safe one.

I think you could fix this in two ways:

The first would be defining the `PrimitiveDataType` to always be a function type:

```js
type ConditionalType<T> = (v: T) => void;
```

Of course in the case above maybe `ConditionalType` is not the right name anymore find a better one. Link to the typescript playground for the case described above -> [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

/* =============== OR  =============== */

Or you can use this other approach where the type parameter `T` is constrained to be a subtype of the `ConditionalType<PrimitiveDataType>` type.
In this case `T` extends `ConditionalType<PrimitiveDataType>` which means that `T` must be a `function type` that takes an argument of type `PrimitiveDataType` and returns `void`.

```js
type PrimitiveDataType = string | number | bigint | boolean | symbol | undefined | null;

type ConditionalType<T> = T extends PrimitiveDataType
  ? (v: T) => void
  : never;

abstract class AbstractClass<T> {
  abstract value: T;
  protected conditionalFunctions: Map<ConditionalType<T>, number | undefined> = new Map();
}

class SomeClass<T extends ConditionalType<PrimitiveDataType>> extends AbstractClass<T> {
  value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    super();
    this.value = value;
  }

  someMethod() {
    for (const someFn of this.conditionalFunctions.keys()) {
        someFn(this.value);        
    }
  }
}
```

Link to the typescript playground for the second approach -> [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbhAIgQ2DgFXGgF4oBnYRAOwHMoAfKagVyQCMI5Gp2FaE1YD3YB7UQBsIOaj3IgOkni2oATCADNBEVT1YSJAbgBQx0JCgBhUWtQIbOCUUgAeAgD4oZAlAgAPYAg1clhEFDRMXHxnCGMoKAB+KAAKdAAuKAIASi9PdFEEVTioDOoITDgTYxx2SjgcAGNhBokcchCAQVqqRuBLVva3TwBvYpq63qh0RxYIDIITeLA4UUCmnSgGm1U7BwkAMRUm+2pyDIBZHDAXa1s0PZihgBpmNk5uJhV1LTLVTzIygB3KCXMDJLImAC+phabRCAGVREgIP04W5fAEgqoQrcdvdqI5HvBkHZInhCMR3J5-IFglAuhMmqjBh4oKN4tMJLN5lV4ltTlQWE1RHBUjM5pkcuz4hQWJBRRDivFgAALBDkAB0nNmXim4sWUGhxXISIg5wgqtEqnBbKVUA0IpS-MoFFN+1kog0UFV6o1-LxJ0ch2oxxsmoA1hAQORwVK7TLXcj3ckfZrtRAIQmE3bofFoZCgA)

/* =============== EDIT 1 =============== */

What about the EDIT 1

The explanation for the error you are encountering when trying to use more than one parameters is pretty much the same, its always related to type narrowing, but the fix is very very simple. You just forgot to make the second parameter optional.

/* =============== FIX EDIT 1 =============== */

```js
type ConditionalType<T> = T extends PrimitiveDataType
  ? (v: T) => void
  : T extends Array<unknown>
  ? (v: T, t?: number) => void
  : never;
```

Here there is the typescript playground with the full code for the fix of EDIT 1 -> [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbhAIgQ2DgFXGgF4oBnYRAOwHMoAfKagVyQCMI5Gp2FaE1YD3YB7UQBsIOaj3IgOkni2oATCADNBEVT1YSJAbgBQx0JCgBhUWtQIbOCUUgAeAgD4oZAlAgAPYAg1clhEFDRMXHxnCGMoKAB+KAAKdAAuKAIASi9PdFEEVTioDJ9-QOCoAEE4OBwQFxUAa2pRAHdqd2Kk1NKAGihgBIzWDi4ckjyCoviRiEw4E3jTHHZKOoBjYQ2JHHIQqrWqHC3LXf23TwBvYtX1k+F0RxYIUqWoMDhRQK2dKA2bKo7A4JAAxFRbezUcgZACyODALmstjQIJilwGo043CYKnUWmoOk8ZEJbSg8LAySyJgAvqYdnsQgBlURICBnRluXwBIKqELIoGo6iOdHwZB2SJ4QjEdyecq8g5HTbADkXDxQG7xJ4SF5vUzxAHQqgsLaiOCpZ6vTI5TXxCgsSDm6nFeLAAAWCHIADptS8vFBfRB3nTiuRWRBYRB3aJVFSNcUNGaUobKBRw6DZKINIMPd7DYKoY5wdRITZvU0ICByFSbS602yM8l3Z6fZbnfE6Z2gA)

Please let me know if this was helpful. :)

Comment: thanks for your answer and time to provide your explanation. My question before edit already was answered by Iain Shelvington and I understand what is going on there. For my Edit 1 I do not understand why TS resolve this conditional type to type connected with an array (It just doesn't make sens to me). FYI the bounty is for answering Edit 1.

Comment: Making 2nd parameter is not a fix, it is a workaround to make it work

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, the distributive type creates the problem. The solution is to narrow your `extends` clause to the desired function type.

First of all, see a [working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbhAIgQ2DgFXGgF4oBnYRAOwHMoAfKagVyQCMI5Gp2FaE1YD3YB7UQBsIOaj3IgOkni2oATCADNBEVT1YSJAbgBQxgPRmooSFADCotagQOcEopAA8BAHxQyBKAgAD2AINXJYRBQ0TFx8dwhzSygoAH4oAAp0AC4oAgBKP190UQRVJJSoXOoITDgTY2toe0c0FzdiL18yDKzc%20GQnWLxCYkKSYtLVQuDQ8My%20vPHJsvzjFPTFgqKoErL1quZargamuwIAZSpBejIW1Sd2hI9KGlpvEwtKgD1UxuJzgB5dgAKz8dgcDza1Fcz1EoIgAGNgB8KilfqZjDh2K8cMioIiJDhyBEAII4qh44C2IkkrpQADeB2xuPx6FcLAguQIJhSYDgolCyJ0BMhjxhEgAYipkc5qORcgBZHBgDz3cWwzo%20AA0zDYnG4TBU6i0NVU3SOAHcoMqwBl8iYAL6mQnEiIXURICA0t1eQIhMKqCIDaIYbAjBK%20WaBskUuBUn10nyMg7siSc7kNFKIhyvFjI0RwLIcrlLFOVCgsSBFh0HFLAAAWCHIADo05zwe2ILyoM6DuRPRBFRBG6JVPby5UNIXMjn5cIB17JbJRBorE3W3OoXLXNLqLLcy2ANYQEDke2FJkVlKLiDLjKN5ttku1ivOlLOx1AA) (based on your original code). I event added 2 samples below to show you a working (string) and not working (object) example. This is btw a good chance to get familiar with the info directive, simply put '//   ^?' in a line and ts playground gives you some hint info.

So, the key to the fix is checking for the desired function (and not just the type):

```
type ConditionalType<T> = ((v: PrimitiveDataType) => void) extends ((v: T) => void)
  ? (v: T) => void
  : never;
```

Read as:

does

a function that takes a PrimitiveDataType param and returns void

extend

a function that takes a param of my type (the generic's T) and returns void

?

If it is, return the desired function type, otherwise, return never.

Comment: `extends` means "is assignable to"

Comment: @vera Thx. I added the text to explain

Comment: @Meri I understand what was the problem in case of my first simple example where conditional type have only 2 possible return types. As you and Iain Shelvington mentioned, the problem was in distributive type, and I think I get it. But when I made `ConditionalType` more complexed, I think TS cannot resolve this type in correct way.  I have also tried your example, but it gives exactly same error as I mentioned in my Edit 1.

Comment: There is also still a question. If TS can resolve, type proposed by @Iain Shelvington, then why it has troubles with a bit more complexed conditional type? + Why it is resolved to type mapped for type that extends an `Array`. If generic parameter `T` of `SomeClass` extends `PrimitiveDataType` then why `ConditionalType` is resolved to typed mapped to `Array` type? I do not see any reason why TS compiler should make such a decision.

Comment: Yesterday I had also chatted with somebody from TS community and I get the answer that: "... typescript just isnt smart enough. ...but typescript kinda can't - partly because it wasn't designed with a builtin solver from the start, partly because they want it to be written in pure javascript (i'm assuming), partly because the actual semantics are actually very very ugly when you dig deep into the language (so there are a lot of compromises, and it's not that easy to tell the solver "oh in this specific situation ignore real logic and just do this instead")".

Comment: So I have decided to open a bug in TS repo. If you are interested: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52144

Comment: @KrzysztofKaczyński, thx, will follow.

Comment: @KrzysztofKaczyński Do you have examples (playground) of the more complex types that fail?

Comment: @KrzysztofKaczyński did you look at my link? It does compile without errors there. I can't repost the (too long) url here, but look at the link titled 'working example' in my response

Comment: @Meir yes check the playground from Edit 1 or this one from TS bug report i have linked in the comment. Yes your link example compiles, but try to make it more complex (as in my edit 1) then it fails